# Find closest solution from a given vector for a linear equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, plot, equation

Let's imagine that on one hand I have an equation like

```
y = 5x + 3
```

and on the other hand I have two vectors of the same size - one representing x-values, other representing y-values (just random values, not a function unfortunately, otherwise this would be quite simple - something like a signal). How can I find the closest pair of values x-y from those two vectors, which will fit or almost fit the equation? Graphically saying I am searching for a point where the equation line would intersect the signal's plot.

Comment: You could compute a separate vector with the required `y` values corresponding to each `x`-value, sort both this vector and the original `y`-vector, then find the closest pair of values using [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-sorted-arrays-number-x-find-pair-whose-sum-closest-x/) O(N)-pass algorithm.

Comment: This is a linear regression problem - see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html

Comment: you can also try to use the curve-fitting tool, by typing cftool in the command line, and use the GUI to explore what expression best fits your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I'm answering is: Given a set of points D = {(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ..., (xN,yN)}, find the point in D which is closest to the line y=5x+3.

**Solution**: A line can be described as all **x** which satisfy 0=**w**' **x** + b where **x** and **w** are 2D vectors and b is a scalar. This is a useful representation because the distance of any point **y** to this line is monotonically related to |**w' y** + b|.

In your case we can rewrite the equation as

```
0 = 5x - y + 3
  = [5,-1].[x;y] + 3
```

so w = [5;-1]; and b = 3.

That motivates us to find the nearest point as follows

```
% 10 random data points (column vector format)
D = rand(2,10)*10-5;

% line parameters
w = [5;-1];
b = 3;

% get the index of the closest point
d = abs(w'*D + b);
[~,idx] = min(d);
```

Example plot

[image]

**Note** This method also generalizes trivially to N-dimensional spaces where 0 = **w'x** + b describes a hyperplane in N-D spaces.

Comment: Thanks, looks like just what I’ve been searching for!

Comment: Can you please explain, what does idx variable stand for? The index of the closest data point in the matrix?

Comment: Yes, `idx` is the index of the point closest to the line. In the example code I posted that point is `D(:,idx)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite equation `y = 5x + 3` in form

```
5 * x - y + 3  = 0
```

or in general:

```
A * x + B * y + C = 0
```

then signed distance (multiplied by `L=Sqrt(A*A+B*B)`) from this line to point `(px, py)` is

```
D = A * px + B * py + C
```

To compare relative distances from given line you can ignore L-scale and just compare absolute value of D for all points (for absolute values divide all equation coefficients by L)

Note also that D changes its sign when points transit into another half of plane relative to line, so you can register signal plot intersection with line by sign change.